# Logstash can't create main pipeline, how do i fix this?

Tags: logstash

I've been working with logstash for a month, and since a week ago i can't seem to make it start. Logstash is running on docker image, version 6.2.4, on a machine aws with linux. I was working fine before so i don't know ehat happened. The only thing my boss did was upgrade from version 6.2.3 to 6.2.4, but the error did not started in that moment but a few days later, so i'm guessing that was not the problem.

I have a logstash.conf file which has my configuration, and the internal logs point to a specific line in "the configuration file" but the funny thing is that this line does not exist since the file has less lines. I read somewhere that logstash merge all the conf files, but i can't seem to find the merged file to check the line. I'm frustrated.

I will paste the logstash.conf file:

```
input {
    beats {
            port => "5044"
        client_inactivity_timeout => "120"
    }
  }
filter {
    ruby {
            code => "event.set('day',event.get('source').split('/')[5].split('-').last)"
    }

ruby {
            code => "event.set('app',event.get('source').split('/')[5].split('-').first)"
    }

    ruby {
            code => "event.set('categoria',event.get('source').split('/').last.split('.').first.split('-')[1])"
    }

    ruby {
            code => "event.set('nodo',event.get('source').split('/')[4])"
    }

    ruby {
            code => "event.set('conFecha',true)"
    }

    if [day] == "A"{
                    ruby {
                            code => "event.set('day',Time.now.getlocal('-03:00').strftime('%Y%m%d'))"
                    }
                    ruby {
                            code => "event.set('conFecha',false)"
                    }
    }

grok {
            patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/pattern/patterns"]
            match => { "message" => "%{SV_TIME:time}, %{SV_TIMESTAMP:numero}, cliente\[%{DATA:client}\], %{WORD:level} , performance - (.)* .*\[%{NUMBER:milliseconds:float}\].*\[com.vtr.servicesvtr.ws.client.factory.([a-z])*.*%{WORD:crm}.%{WORD:grupo}.%{WORD:method}.*.(ejecutar)\]" }
            add_field => {
                    "tipo" => "SOA"
                    "fechahora" => "%{day} %{time}"
                    "performance" => "performance"
            }
    }

    grok {
            patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/pattern/patterns"]
            match => { "message" => "%{SV_TIME:time}, %{SV_TIMESTAMP:numero}, cliente\[%{DATA:client}\], %{WORD:level} , performance - (.)* .*\[%{NUMBER:milliseconds:float}\].*\[/%{SV_PACKAGE:microservicio}/%{DATA:url}\]" }
            add_field => {
                    "tipo" => "MS"
                    "fechahora" => "%{day} %{time}"
                    "performance" => "performance"
            }
       }

    if [performance] != "performance"{

            grok {
                    patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/pattern/patterns"]
                    match => { "message" => "%{SV_TIME:time}, %{SV_TIMESTAMP:numero}, cliente\[%{DATA:client}\], %{WORD:level}.*\, %{GREEDYDATA:resultado}" }
                    add_field => {
                            "tipo" => "AUDIT"
                            "fechahora" => "%{day} %{time}"
                            "auditoria" => "auditoria"
                    }
            }
    }

    if [performance] != "performance" and [auditoria] != "auditoria"{
            grok {
                    patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/pattern/patterns"]
                    match => { "message" => "%{SV_DATE_TIME:fecha}.* seguridad  \- %{DATA:usuario}\|%{DATA:rut}\|%{DATA:resultado} \-> %{GREEDYDATA:metodo}" }
                    add_field => {
                            "tipo" => "SEGURIDAD"
                            "fechahora" => "%{fecha}"
                            "su" => "su"
                    }
            }
            mutate {
                lowercase => [ "usuario" ]
            }

            date {
                    match => ["fechahora", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
            }
    }

    if [su] != "su"{
            date {
                    match => ["fechahora", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
            }
    }

    date {
            match => ["timestamp" , "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
            target => "@timestamp"
    }
 }
output {
       if [performance] == "performance" and [url] != "manage/health"{
           if [conFecha] {
               elasticsearch {
                      hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                      index => "%{[app_id]}-performances-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
              }

           }else {
               elasticsearch {
                      hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                       index => "temp-%{[app_id]}-performances-%
{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        }
    }else if [auditoria] == "auditoria" {
        if [conFecha] {
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                    index => "%{[app_id]}-auditoria-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        }else {
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                    index => "temp-%{[app_id]}-auditoria-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        }

    }

    if [performance] == "performance" and [milliseconds] >= 1000 and [url] != "manage/health"{
        if [conFecha] {
            elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                    index => "%{[app_id]}-performance-scache-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        }else {
                elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                    index => "temp-%{[app_id]}-performance-scache-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

I will also paste the logs:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now 
configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-04-27T15:59:06,770][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] 
Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", 
:directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-04-27T15:59:06,879][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] 
Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", 
:directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-04-27T15:59:13,551][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting 
Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.4"}
[2018-04-27T15:59:17,073][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] 
Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
 [2018-04-27T15:59:27,711][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to 
 execute action 
 {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, 
 :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of 
 #, input, filter, output at line 205, column 1 (byte 6943) after ", 
 :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
 core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", 
 "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in 
`compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
 core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", 
 "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in `map'", 
  "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
  core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", 
  "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:51:in 
  `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
  core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in `initialize'", 
  "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
  core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in `execute'", 
  "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in 
 `block 
  in converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
  core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", 
 "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in 
`block 
 in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", 
 "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in ` 
 converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
 core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in `block in 
 converge_state_and_update'", 
 "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in 
 `with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in `converge_state_and_update'", 
 "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in 
 `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
 core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in `block in execute'", 
 "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-
  0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}
```

I really hope you can help me guys. I'm desperate. Bye

Comment: I haven't found anything wrong with your configuration, so one possible solution is to remove a filter from the configuration, try to run it. If it works, you've found the problem. If not, do it again until you've found the part creating the problem.

Comment: Will do that for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by deleting all the files inside the config directory, since logstash was doing merge of all files. In this case, it was the uup file. Anyway, logstash creates them again later thanks to the docker image.